# TSQL Why converting VARCHAR to DATETIME milliseconds change value

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've a problem with Datetime conversion in TSQL (SQL 2005). I'm trying to convert this varchar value "`2011-12-10 12:48:56.066`" to Datetime but I've encountered a problem. The Datetime value change to "`2011-12-10 12:48:56.067`" that is different in one millisecond from the original. This occur with other value (ex:"`2011-12-10 12:48:56.067`") but not with other ("`2011-12-10 12:48:56.013`" or "`2011-12-10 12:48:56.040`").

Anyone can explain why millisecond change converting a varchar to datetime?

Comment: it's 2/30 @MattBall to have a value of 0.067

Comment: @Bryan thanks... I am not yet awake

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the representation at that resolution. It's not an error.

The `datetime` type has a resolution of 3.33 ms

[If you were using SQL Server 2008 you could use `datetime2` which has up to a 100 ns precision.]

Answer (score 0):

The .066 is actually the continuous number (0.06666667). Upon converting, the 0.066 rounds into 0.067